# How to Show Customize or Dynamic Descriptor/Merchant Name in Cardholder's Account Statement

Tags: php, payment-gateway, cybersource

I am using Cybersource for Capturing Payment and it is working Fine.
Now I want to Change the descriptor or merchant name as per requirement .
by default Descriptor name is showing Merchant Business name which is ok.

Documentation Saying that i need to send "invoiceHeader_merchantDescriptor" in request to Change the Descriptor Name . and What should be the Payout it is not clearly Declared and that particular parameter not even showing in request parameters in Documentation.
[Cyber Source Documentation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWsVG.png)
document Link - https://developer.cybersource.com/content/cybsdeveloper2021/amer/en/library/documentation/sbc/SB_Merchant_Descriptors/SB_Merchant_Descriptors.pdf
I did the Same

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBpch.png)

But its Not Working.

```
$orderInformationArr = ["amountDetails" => $orderInformationAmountDetails,"billTo" => $orderInformationBillTo];

$orderInformation = new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsOrderInformation($orderInformationArr);

$merchantDefinedInformation = array();

$merchantDefinedInformation_0 = [ "name" => "AirlineServices","alternateName" => "AirlineServices"];

$merchantDefinedInformation = new CyberSource\Model\Ptsv2paymentsMerchantInformationMerchantDescriptor($merchantDefinedInformation_0);

$requestObjArr = ["clientReferenceInformation" => $clientReferenceInformation,"processingInformation" => $processingInformation,"paymentInformation" => $paymentInformation,"orderInformation" => $orderInformation,"invoiceHeader_merchantDescriptor" => "AirlineServices"];

$requestObj = new CyberSource\Model\CreatePaymentRequest($requestObjArr);
```

Comment: Can you link to that documentation, instead of showing just a screenshot?

Comment: When you show code, please format it properly - https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

You screenshot indicate that you are using TSYS processor.

In the document it says that you need to contact Cybersource support to have your account configured to use the feature.

If you haven't then I would suggest you reach out to Cybersource support to have them configure it for your account and then try again.

From your field names you appear to be using REST API. If REST then you need to place it in `merchantInformation`.

Example:

```
"merchantInformation": {
    "merchantDescriptor": {
       "name": ""
     }
```

You can refer to their developer center to see how the request should be constructed:
https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_capture_capture-a-payment